# Xcode Debug View Hierarchy: Unable to capture view hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

While trying to debug my view hierarchy, I get the following error:

> Error:    Unable to capture view hierarchy.
>   Details:  No plist data for fetching view hierarchy: error evaluating expression “(id)[(Class)objc_getClass("DBGViewDebuggerSupport_iOS") fetchViewHierarchyWithOptions:(id)[(Class)objc_getClass("NSDictionary") dictionaryWithObjects:(id)[(id)[(id)[(Class)objc_getClass("NSArray") arrayWithObject:(id)[(Class)objc_getClass("NSNumber") numberWithBool:1]] arrayByAddingObject:(id)[(id)[(Class)objc_getClass("NSArray") arrayWithObject:@"_UIVisualEffectBackdropView"] arrayByAddingObject:@"_UIBackdropEffectView"]] arrayByAddingObject:(id)[(Class)objc_getClass("NSNumber") numberWithBool:0]] forKeys:(id)[(id)[(id)[(Class)objc_getClass("NSArray") arrayWithObject:@"DBGViewDebuggerUseLayersAsSnapshots"] arrayByAddingObject:@"DBGViewDebuggerEffectViewsToSnapshotAsImage"] arrayByAddingObject:@"DBGViewDebuggerAlwaysEncodeLayers"]]]”: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGSTOP.
>   The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
>   Method:   -[DBGAbstractViewDescriber handleFetchedViewInfo:fetchError:resultHandler:]
>   Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.

Anyone got a clue?

Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)
Simulator: iPhone 6 (10.2)

Thanks!

Comment: The error message asks you to file a bug report with Apple. I suggest you do so.

Answer (score 2):

Actually  me also got the same type of error, but the truth is our app must in **Running state**. Because the "Debug View capture hierarchy" area appears only while the app is running.

See my screen shot

In Step 1: Select your app first

In Step 2: Now select Debug hierarchy button

[image]

If this doesn't work then go to **Debug** in menu on the top bar of Xcode

->Debug -> view debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy

I solved my problem like this.

Comment: That also doesn't work for me. I get an error with both methods:
`Unable to capture the view hierarchy
Domain: DBGViewDebuggerErrorDomain
Code: 0
Failure Reason: "MyApp" encountered an unexpected error when processing the request for a view hierarchy snapshot.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-01-09 20:30:43 +0000";
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 547420;
    Environment = "Xcode 14.0 (14A309) debugging iPhone 13 Pro iOS 16.0 (20A362).";
}`

Answer (score 1):

Since Apple Silicon can run iOS apps natively, you want to debug its views too. If you use Xcode in fullscreen mode, your app will change state and become inactive when you switch focus. So as [@iOS said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54033858/7996650), you can't get the snapshot.

Just keep Xcode and iOS app in the same workspace (or on desktop), so iOS app will be in focus. It is still laggy for me, but maybe it is current Xcode's fault.

Comment: That also doesn't work for me. I get an error with both methods:
`Unable to capture the view hierarchy
Domain: DBGViewDebuggerErrorDomain
Code: 0
Failure Reason: "MyApp" encountered an unexpected error when processing the request for a view hierarchy snapshot.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-01-09 20:30:43 +0000";
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 547420;
    Environment = "Xcode 14.0 (14A309) debugging iPhone 13 Pro iOS 16.0 (20A362).";
}`

Comment: Removing xcode and simulator from fullscreen mode to normal mode fixed this issue for me.