# Xcode 9 Debug View Hierarchy BUG

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode9

When I update to xcode 9, and I click "Debug View Hierarchy", it shows "Unable to capture view hierarchy"

What can I do about this?

[image: log message]

Comment: Have you filed a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com?

Comment: Try my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381572/xcode-debug-view-hierarchy-unable-to-capture-view-hierarchy/54033858#54033858

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it working here is what you need to do:

simply you need to get your app running, because the "Debug View capture hierarchy" area appears only while the app is running

if this doesn't work then you need to go to debug menu on the top bar of Xcode Debug> view debugging > Capture View Hierarchy

if this doesn't work either (which I doubt!) then go on Xcode preferences > Key binding  and check if there is any conflicted shortcut Keys.