# Unable to capture view hierarchy

Tags: xcode9

> Error:    Unable to capture view hierarchy. Details:  Log Title: Data
>   source expression execution failure. Log Details: error evaluating
>   expression “(id)[[(Class)objc_getClass("DBGTargetHub") sharedHub]
>   performRequestWithRequestInBase64:@"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"]”:
>   error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,
>   address=0x0).

The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

Comment: Got same problem, didn't fix it?

Comment: Have you filed a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com?

Comment: I have the same problem, with a legacy application. Compiled with Xcode9.

Comment: Try my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381572/xcode-debug-view-hierarchy-unable-to-capture-view-hierarchy/54033858#54033858

Answer (score 4):

You likely have a bug somewhere in the implementation of a framework override. At least it was the case for me: a forced unwrapping of an optional `nil` value. Since the debugger executes the above statement, I could not get a stack trace of where the problem had happened.

My idea was to emulate the debugger's statement in my code directly. Since you won't have access to `DBGTargetHub`'s interface, I went with using the Objective-C runtime functions.

```
NSString *data = @"YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBA[...]";

Class DbgTargetHub = objc_getClass("DBGTargetHub");

SEL sel = sel_getUid("sharedHub");

id sharedHub = ((id(*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend)(DbgTargetHub, sel);

sel = sel_getUid("performRequestWithRequestInBase64:");

id result = ((id(*)(id, SEL, NSString*))objc_msgSend)(sharedHub, sel, data);
```

I was able to generate a stack trace from this which I could use to locate my problem.

Would be interested to know if this helped anybody.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me track down a crash in a Swift subclass of NSCell (see https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4756)

Answer (score 1):

For me this was a really weird SwiftUI bug caused by having a Section(header: that was a Divider view. Changed it to a Rectangle view and it all started working again...

I was only able to track this down by commenting out views until things worked again. Hope this helps some poor soul