# Xcode 9: "Unable to capture view hierarchy"

Tags: xcode

Whenever I tap on the visual debugger while my app is running in the simulator I get this message.  I've been using the visual debugger for months and it just stopped working.  I'm running Version 9.2 (9C40b).  Is this a known bug?  I've tried cleaning derived data, restarting, etc..

Comment: Try my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381572/xcode-debug-view-hierarchy-unable-to-capture-view-hierarchy/54033858#54033858