# Xcode Error when launching application Error: Unable to Capture View Hierarchy

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I have tried to load the flutter app, that I created, on my phone, but when I try to launch it, it shows a white screen or crashes directly.

The error I am getting is:

```
Error:    Unable to Capture View Hierarchy.
Details:  Log Title: Data source expression execution failure.
Log Details: error evaluating expression “(id)[[(Class)objc_getClass("DBGTargetHub") sharedHub] performRequestWithRequestInBase64:@"…"]”: error: <user expression 1>:1:14: use of undeclared identifier 'objc_getClass'
(id)[[(Class)objc_getClass("DBGTargetHub") sharedHub] performRequestWithRequestInBase64:@"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"]
             ^

Log Method: -[DBGDataSourceConnectionLibViewDebugger _executeLLDBExpression:forRequest:onPotentialThread:iteration:]_block_invoke
Method:   -[DBGViewDebugger _initiateInitialRequestWithDataSourceVersion:]_block_invoke
Environment: Xcode 11.4.1 (11E503a) debugging iPhone 8 (Model A1863, A1905, A1906, A1907) iOS 13.3.1 (17D50).
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
```

I don't know how to fix this?

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54033858/12880676

Comment: @Lunedor The problem is that when you created your app in flutter you can't see the view hierarchy  in Xcode.